# AWS Greengrass Stream Manager on Windows fails

Tags: windows, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

We are having an issue with running the stream manager component on an AWS Greengrass Windows (latest version 2.8) installation. We followed all instructions for installation but still with each deployment try we get the following exception:

> aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException.

Any idea? We tried installing an older version of greengrass (2.7) but same issue.

It would be great if you could help us. Thx

```
022-10-26T18:22:10.639Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule.mapDb(DataStoreModule.java:103) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.639Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_MapDbFactory.get(DataStoreModule_MapDbFactory.java:29) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.639Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_MapDbFactory.get(DataStoreModule_MapDbFactory.java:10) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.639Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.639Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_MessageStreamDefDaoFactory.get(DataStoreModule_MessageStreamDefDaoFactory.java:32) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.640Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_MessageStreamDefDaoFactory.get(DataStoreModule_MessageStreamDefDaoFactory.java:11) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.640Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.640Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_LogStoreFactory.get(DataStoreModule_LogStoreFactory.java:59) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.640Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_LogStoreFactory.get(DataStoreModule_LogStoreFactory.java:15) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.642Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.642Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.StreamServerModule_StreamServerFactory.get(StreamServerModule_StreamServerFactory.java:69) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.642Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.StreamServerModule_StreamServerFactory.get(StreamServerModule_StreamServerFactory.java:16) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.642Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.642Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DaggerStreamManagerServiceComponent.streamServer(DaggerStreamManagerServiceComponent.java:284) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.643Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.StreamManagerService.main(StreamManagerService.java:44) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.643Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. Caused by: java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.643Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at sun.nio.fs.WindowsUserPrincipals.lookup(WindowsUserPrincipals.java:147) ~[?:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.643Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem$LookupService$1.lookupPrincipalByGroupName(WindowsFileSystem.java:250) ~[?:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.644Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.common.windows.WindowsPlatform.conditionalSetPermissions(WindowsPlatform.java:68) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.644Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule.mapDb(DataStoreModule.java:96) ~[AWSGreengrassGreenlake-1.0-super.jar:?]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.644Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. ... 14 more. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.758Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. 2022 Okt. 26 20:22:10,757 [INFO] (main) com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.server.GreengrassCoreV2SDKWrapper: Socket file path: \\.\pipe\NucleusNamedPipe-Cgreengrassv2. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.798Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. Okt. 26, 2022 8:22:10 NACHM. software.amazon.awssdk.eventstreamrpc.EventStreamRPCConnection$1 onConnectionSetup. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.798Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. INFORMATION: Socket connection \\.\pipe\NucleusNamedPipe-Cgreengrassv2:8033 to server result [AWS_ERROR_SUCCESS]. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.846Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. Okt. 26, 2022 8:22:10 NACHM. software.amazon.awssdk.eventstreamrpc.EventStreamRPCConnection$1 onProtocolMessage. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.846Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. INFORMATION: Connection established with event stream RPC server. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STARTING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.929Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. 2022 Okt. 26 20:22:10,929 [INFO] (main) com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.server.GreengrassCoreV2SDKHandler: Stream Manager reporting the state: ERRORED. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:10.932Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stdout. 2022 Okt. 26 20:22:10,929 [INFO] (Thread-0) com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.StreamManagerService: Shutting down StreamManager services. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.127Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.128Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule.mapDb(DataStoreModule.java:103). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.128Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_MapDbFactory.get(DataStoreModule_MapDbFactory.java:29). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.128Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_MapDbFactory.get(DataStoreModule_MapDbFactory.java:10). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.128Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.128Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_MessageStreamDefDaoFactory.get(DataStoreModule_MessageStreamDefDaoFactory.java:32). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.128Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_MessageStreamDefDaoFactory.get(DataStoreModule_MessageStreamDefDaoFactory.java:11). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.128Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.129Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_LogStoreFactory.get(DataStoreModule_LogStoreFactory.java:59). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.129Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule_LogStoreFactory.get(DataStoreModule_LogStoreFactory.java:15). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.129Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.129Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.StreamServerModule_StreamServerFactory.get(StreamServerModule_StreamServerFactory.java:69). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.129Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.StreamServerModule_StreamServerFactory.get(StreamServerModule_StreamServerFactory.java:16). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.129Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.129Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DaggerStreamManagerServiceComponent.streamServer(DaggerStreamManagerServiceComponent.java:284). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.130Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.StreamManagerService.lambda$registerShutdownHook$0(StreamManagerService.java:64). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.130Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.131Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. Caused by: java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipalNotFoundException. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.131Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsUserPrincipals.lookup(WindowsUserPrincipals.java:147). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.131Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem$LookupService$1.lookupPrincipalByGroupName(WindowsFileSystem.java:250). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.131Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.common.windows.WindowsPlatform.conditionalSetPermissions(WindowsPlatform.java:68). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.132Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. at com.amazonaws.iot.greengrass.streammanager.dagger.DataStoreModule.mapDb(DataStoreModule.java:96). {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
2022-10-26T18:22:11.132Z [WARN] (Copier) aws.greengrass.StreamManager: stderr. ... 15 more. {scriptName=services.aws.greengrass.StreamManager.lifecycle.startup.script, serviceName=aws.greengrass.StreamManager, currentState=STOPPING}
```